# Is there any way to reduce the feather in photoshop after you have created your mask?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, png, photo-editing

I am new to Photoshop and was trying to make an image cutout. I used a pen tool to make the selection around the image.

What I did is I gave a feather of 2px after making the selection.
Now that the image cutout is not looking that much good.

So I want to remove the feather I gave.

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: Try using Photoshop's select and mask functionality. It's the best way to select around hair and make it look natural and not like a cutout. Look for tutorials on youtube. There [are many](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Photoshop+select+and+mask).

Answer (score 0):

If it's in the mask only, select the mask icon in the layers pane and apply curves to fade the grey zone. It unfortunately affects the whole image and can make the result worse where the feathering happens to be a good idea. A workaround is to paint carefully black or white to the mask to areas where the feathering is not so good idea.